# hive thrift server is hanging

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, thrift

I developed an application in that, I am connecting to hive server1 on 10000 port using JDBC. After performing some DDL commands i'm closing the connection.

When I was testing this jar, after running it few times(it is working fine for few times), hive is hanging. Don't know the exact reason. I am using a pseudo cluster for this purpose.

After killing the hive thrift server and restarting the hive(through cloudera manager) and thrift server from console it is working fine. Again after few times running the jar leading to hanging of hive.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in hive.
The answer for this question you will find here..

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-dev/201307.mbox/%3CJIRA.12655818.1372790903944.200365.1372791200636@arcas%3E

Answer (score 0):

Setting the below hive property in hivesite.xml file would solve this exception.

`<property>
<name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>`